# Mobile application with Drupal services

Tags: android, ios, web-services, drupal, mobile

I will be very thankful if someone can guide me which is the best approach when using Drupal's CMS functionality combined with the Services module for communicating with a mobile application. What I am trying to achieve is create a mobile quiz application and manage the content using Drupal.

The questions that arise are:

- How to add questions - do I have to develop a custom Drupal module,
  custom content type or something else?
- How to expose the newly created content using the Services layer?

The Drupal version I plan to use is 7.

Or maybe there is a better solution than using Drupal for what I am trying to achieve?

EDIT:

Another question is how can I keep track of the user answers/stats - how to organize it, do I have to create a DB table myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question:

What I did is I made a separate module which uses the built-in Drupal hooks in order to create the database - `hook_schema`, created a service using the hooks again - `hook_services_resources` and also created a simple administration page for it using the Form API.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Drupal module that may be able to help in this venture:

http://www.drupal.org/project/drupalgap

It uses Services and Views Datasource (Views JSON) to be able to communicate with mobile applications built with PhoneGap and jQueryMobile.

To answer your questions: to create new nodes (Questions) you would use the Node Create Service Resource. Then you can use Views Datasource (Views JSON) to retrieve the newly created content.

I have a blog post which covers this idea in detail:

http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/android-app-with-drupal-7-services-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 1):

In my company we've created our own drupal module. The module creates JSON files from the drupal content which we then get from our apps through HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: Is this content custom, or it is like the generic nodes that Drupal has?

Comment: The content is based on drupals nodes. We then have a text file on our server indicating the mapping from drupal nodes to json.

Comment: My point is I need more custom content - like a form where I can add a Question, possible answers, right answer, etc. and then expose this "Question" object. Is this achievable through the "nodes"? Sorry If my questions are dumb, but I am very new to Drupal

Comment: Heh well I'm an Android man not a Drupal/php guy so kinda the wrong guy to shot at but with my experience yes this is very much possible. What I would do is to create a bunch of nodes with both questions and answers. Its up to you if you want to download all the questions at runtime or want to handle communication for each question.